# What is the correct way to get strings from the Main Form in another form? C#

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I'm having issues passing strings from my main form to another form named unlockForm.

In my mainForm I create each string like so

```
public string race
    {
        get;set;
    }
```

I've been trying to access them from the unlockForm, but creating a new mainForm like this

```
mainForm mainScreen = new mainForm();
unlockRace = mainform.race;
```

gives me a StackOverflowException was unhandled error on the first line.

I haven't had this problem when making new forms in the Main Form, so I'm wondering what the correct way to do this is.

Edit:

Here is the entire code as requested by @deathismyfriend

This is the mainForm Constructor

```
public mainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

This is the code in the mainForm that updates the race string.

```
public string race
    {
        get;set;
    }


private void raceUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (raceBox.Text == "Human")
        {
            if (infoText != humanText)
            {
                infoText = humanText;

                infoboxUpdate(sender, e);
            }
        }
        else if (raceBox.Text == "Troll")
        {
            if (infoText != trollText)
            {
                infoText = trollText;

                infoboxUpdate(sender, e);
            }
        }

        race = raceBox.Text;
        if (race == "") 
        {
            race = "Unspecified";
        }
    }
```

Here is the code in my unlockForm

```
public unlockForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        getStats();
    }

    mainForm mainScreen = new mainForm();

    private void getStats()
    {
        race = mainScreen.race;
    }
```

Edit #2:

Even when I make my code for unlockForm the following

```
public unlockForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //getStats();
    }

    mainForm mainScreen = new mainForm();
```

I still receive the error

Comment: You never set race before calling it.

Comment: Even when I remove calling race, I still get the error

Comment: You need to set mainform.race before calling it.

Comment: @deathismyfriend I have, and I've removed the `unlockRace = mainForm.race;` from the code entirely. Just using `mainForm mainScreen = new mainForm();` causes the error.

Comment: Can you post the actual code. Also post mainform constructor.

Comment: @deathismyfriend updated the original post

Comment: You are first creating the mainscreen variable. Then you initialize components. Then you get stats which sets mainscreen.race. This variable has never been set. You can change this by setting the race variable to "Unspecified" after initializing the components in the mainscreen class.

Comment: @deathismyfriend
Setting the race after initializing isn't working either.

I don't think the string is the issue. I can make the unlockForm contain nothing except `mainForm mainScreen = new mainForm();` and I still crash

Comment: Can you provide the exact error message ? Also do you mean you are commenting out everything in the unlockForm constructor ?

Comment: You are getting `race` from newly created instance of main form which is wrong. You must get reference of same instance from constructor of unlock form.

Comment: @deathismyfriend I updated the main form to show what I mean. It's a brand new Form without any other code. The exact error thrown says  "System.StackOverflowException was unhandled HResult=-2147023895 Message=Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown. InnerException:"

Comment: @M.NasserJavaid How do I get it from the same instance, rather than creating a new instance? I'm unable to access the mainForm without creating the new instance.

Comment: Why are you not getting `race` string from constructor. eg. `public unlockForm(string race) {_race = race;}` and in main form `var unlockForm = new UnloackForm("Human")`

Comment: @M.NasserJavaid This works, but can I use it to send multiple strings, ints, etc? For example I want to send a gender string, and an age int as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways
1:

In `UnlockForm.cs`

```
private string _race;
public UnlockForm(string race)
{
 _race = race;
}
```

In `MainForm.cs`

```
private void LuanchUnlockForm()
{
 var unlockForm = new UnlockForm("Human");
 unlockForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

2nd way:

In `UnlockForm.cs`

```
private MainForm _mainForm;
public UnlockForm(MainForm mainForm)
{
 _mainForm= mainForm;
}
private void GetRace()
{
 var myRace = _mainForm.race;
}
```

In `MainForm.cs`

```
private void LuanchUnlockForm()
{
 var unlockForm = new UnlockForm(this);
 unlockForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

If you want to send multiple string do the following

Create new class just like as

`Human.cs`

```
public class Human
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Age { get; set; }
            public string Address { get; set; }
            // or anything you want
        }
```

now 
In `UnlockForm.cs`

```
private Human _human;
public UnlockForm(Human human)
{
  _human= human;
}
private void GetHumanAttributes()
{
  var age = _human.Age; 
  //and others ...
}
```

In `MainForm.cs`

```
private void LuanchUnlockForm()
{
 var human = new Human();
 human.Name = "name";
 human.Age = 19;
 // others
 var unlockForm = new UnlockForm(human);
 unlockForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: Took some tinkering, but I did finally get this working! Thanks so much for all the help!